AWS Lambda - Access Denied due to "UnknownError"
I have a strange problem with accessing AWS Lambda functions. To be more precise, whenever I try to go to the dashboard or see the list of functions, I receive denied access with "UnknownError" (as shown on the screen). The same is true for my coworker (only we have access to AWS resources). On top of all that, apparently, our lambda functions have stopped working as well.

We thought it was just a bug from Amazon's side, which would be fixed by itself, but it's already been 2 days and I wasn't able to find any information or resolution to this problem by myself. We aren't able to contact AWS support because apparently, it requires a separate subscription.
Has anyone faced such a problem? What was the reason?
Note:
I have full administrative permissions. The IAM Roles were not changed in any way. The following permissions are present:
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            ...

            "lambda:CreateEventSourceMapping",
            "lambda:CreateFunction",
            "lambda:DeleteEventSourceMapping",
            "lambda:DeleteFunction",
            "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration",
            "lambda:ListEventSourceMappings",
            "lambda:ListFunctions",

            ...
        ],
        "Resource": "*"

.

        "Action": [
            ...

            "lambda:Create*",
            "lambda:Delete*",
            "lambda:Get*",
            "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "lambda:PublishVersion",
            "lambda:Update*",
            "lambda:List*",

            ...
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"


do you have right Role and Permission to access lambda service, i guess you are using IAM managed user therefore please check if you have permission to access and perform action in lambda. will you be able to share the permissio tab in your IAM for this user and show me the policy attached to it.

You mentioned that you have full administrative permissions but then reference IAM policies that show only Lambda permissions. What do you mean by "full administrative permissions"? Do you have permissions for CloudWatch, for example? The dashboard shows a mix of Lambda data and CloudWatch data.

If you check the developer tools on the Dashboard, you can see that it makes requests to a bunch of non-Lambda endpoints, mainly related to CloudWatch:

monitoring.<region>.amazonaws.com
logs.<region>.amazonaws.com

The Dashboard includes metrics from CloudWatch, which require permissions outside of the Lambda Namespace. I didn't do a deep dive, but some of the actions I'm seeing are:

logs:DescribeMetricFilters
cloudwatch:GetMetricData

You should probably add these to your policy.
